# Hoping I can see NGINX success screen one day

Tags: nginx, centos6

Total Linux noob here, but lots of experience with PHP, MySQL, OOP, Java, Eclipse, etc. I have previously tried to dive into the Linux pond several times, but always retreated when the pain became too great. And it looks like it has happened again. Any help would sincerely be appreciated.

I booked a small Centos 6.9 VPS and tried to install NGINX, and this simple thing has taken me two days, dozens of browser search tabs open, and still no joy to see the "NGINX Working" screen in a browser. I tried several different tutorials, but the one that looked most complete is:

[https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/configure-nginx-on-a-centos-6-server/][1]

I ran update as recommended. I installed MariaDB instead of MySQL. I am using puTTY and SSH Explorer.

nginx -t reports successful.

```
$ nginx -t

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I can ping the server IP.

If I try to restart NGINX, I get a permissions error which I don't understand, because I was doing everything as user root:

```
$ service nginx restart

nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed [root@centos6:/etc/nginx/conf.d ]
```

Is this a fatal error?

Next question: If I do this step by step, and only try to access the server by IP, please could someone tell me in the simplest possible terms how to change the default config files? I tried a few tutorials, but sadly still no joy. Some tutorials don't make any changes to config files, and it should just work, but nope. And some tutorials make config changes mostly using domain names, I don't have a domain name (that would be next step), and nope not working. Any other commands I could run to shed some light on what is happening?

**Adding requested info thank you sir:**

My ambitious goal is to try to get WP Multisite working, but I thought I was being reasonable in only expecting to see a success screen. No, sorry, I used Yum install and didn't work out of the box. Just wondering how could it know my IP address out of the box? It doesn't need that for configuration? Sorry for total noob questions.

Contents of nginx.conf are unchanged from install:

```
        # For more information on configuration, see:
    #   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
    #   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

    user nginx;
    worker_processes auto;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

    # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;
        keepalive_timeout   65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type        application/octet-stream;

        # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
        # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
        # for more information.
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    }

Contents of error log as requested:

    2017/04/25 13:35:17 [emerg] 2563#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8000 failed (13: Permission denied)
    2017/04/25 13:41:40 [emerg] 2606#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8000 failed (13: Permission denied)
    2017/04/25 15:13:41 [emerg] 14498#0: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
    2017/04/25 15:14:41 [emerg] 14513#0: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
    2017/04/25 16:41:46 [emerg] 14591#0: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)

Additional info.

Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (unchanged from installer)

#
# The default server
#

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show nginx.conf What is your end goal, and what did you do so far? If you simply do yum install nginx it will work out of the box. Also please post contents of the nginx error log.

Comment: Are you sure you are root? Can you try sudo restart nginx? Also please post the config of the vhost. /etc/nginx/conf.d/ or /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/..

Comment: Thanks again @mzhaase sir. This was a fresh VPS and I wouldn't know how to create a user or group or change user yet, so under those conditions I am assuming I am root. Results are restart are in my post and there is a permissions error. After 'yum install nginx' there was no folder site-enabled. I did see that mentioned in some tutorials and it's a mystery why I don't have it.

Comment: Please try sudo restart nginx. In /etc/nginx/conf.d you should have some config file? If not you do not have a website configured yet.

Comment: OK thanks @mzhaase, yes I understand that I don't have a website configured yet thanks. That is the next step. First step is get the success screen by IP address only. That should work out of the box as mentioned, but it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: No it shouldn't work, because you have to configure nginx to respond to requests. Usually there is some default file in /etc/nginx/conf.d that responds to requests to any IP with the default 'it works' screen. If that doesn't exist you have to create it.

Comment: Thank you @mzhaase There are three files in /etc/nginx/conf.d put there by install and I didn't change them. I was mentioning about sites-enabled folder, I don't have one and that is next step. So with those three files it should work by IP access but it doesn't.

Comment: This sounds very much like an selinux problem. Set selinux to permissive mode, see if it works then.

Comment: Please note mentioned earlier: Results are NGINX RESTART are in my post and there is a PERMISSIONS ERROR. Ok thanks @gerald-schneider for additional info I have no idea what selinux is so it's back to Google.

Comment: After setting "setenforce 0", result is:$ service nginx restart
Stopping nginx: [FAILED]
Starting nginx: [  OK  ]

Comment: $ sudo service nginx restart
Stopping nginx: [  OK  ]
Starting nginx: [  OK  ]

Comment: OK thanks @gerald-schneider permissions error seems to have been fixed. Still no success screen by IP access. Any other ideas thanks.

Comment: Contents of default.conf are unchanged from installer.

Comment: Right, what happens when you do curl localhost?

Comment: OK thanks @mzhaase wait a second I am not on local host. I am accessing the server over internet by IP.

Comment: thanks for your help @mzhaase And this begs the question, how could the installer know my IP address since it didn't ask for it? So then, how could it possibly work out of the box? Perhaps there is an explanation. Am I thinking about this correctly? Do I need to put my server IP in one of the config files? Which one?

Comment: If you run curl localhost on the machine, then it will try to connect to itself.. Why would the server need it's own IP address? You are trying to connect to it from the outside. Per default it just answers to everything.

Comment: @mzhaase result of $ curl localhost
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'localhost'

Comment: That's not normal. What is your VPS provider? Meanwhile, try curl 127.0.0.1

Comment: @mzhaase Ok great news! We are getting somewhere now thanks so much! My host is cambo.host. I need the VPS server located there in Cambodia for low latency.

Comment: If it answers to curl 127.0.0.1, then the server is running. Simply open port 80 in your firewall.

Comment: @mzhaase Amazing, curl 127.0.0.1 replied with the NGINX success message! Outstanding!! Now I don't know anything about any firewall or how to open a port, so if you could REPLY to the original question (not a comment) and tell me how to do that, and it works, I will mark it as accepted answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: you definitely want to add `localhost 127.0.0.1` to /etc/resolv.conf, many things might not work otherwise.

Comment: OK thanks for info @mzhaase I'm not sure how to do that, so again it's back to Google. I have never seen this mentioned in ANY of the dozens of tutorials I studied, so thanks for this critical info.

Comment: File contents of resolve.conf:   $ cat 'resolv.conf' | less
 ; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search cambo.host
nameserver 203.217.168.27
nameserver 203.217.168.36

Comment: New problem: when I try to EDIT the file resolv.conf using SSH Explorer, it returns error "Invalid Username/Password Returned by Server". But I don't supply any username/password.

Comment: @mzhaase, You must have meant `/etc/hosts` file, not `resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, I finally got it to work! Thanks to the debugging help above, it was clear that the problem was not NGINX but IPTABLES. But being such a noobie I had no idea what was wrong, I just knew that it wasn't working.

CAUSE OF PROBLEM: Apparently the CENTOS 6 default IPTABLES config file includes a rule at the end to block all traffic. Adding another rule AFTER that to open port 80 accomplishes nothing. This explains why it didn't work.

SOLUTION: This post explains the whole thing:

http://www.binarytides.com/open-http-port-iptables-centos/

Pasted from that article in case it disappears:

Default IPTABLES config:

```
[root@dhcppc2 ~]# iptables --line -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      273 22516 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
2        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
5      271 36456 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 172 packets, 24494 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
[root@dhcppc2 ~]#
```

Command to correctly insert new port 80 rule at line 5:

```
# iptables -I INPUT 5 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Resulting Config file:

```
[root@dhcppc2 ~]# iptables --line -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      291 23868 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
2        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
5        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
6      286 38524 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 608 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
[root@dhcppc2 ~]#
```

Thank you again to all who assisted.

Answer (score 0):

Installing nginx is very simple:

1. Install nginx with you package manager
2. Open the correct port in your firewall

For 1, simply do: `yum install nginx`. For 2, you can do:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Per default, nginx answers to any request, from any hostname or IP.

Comment: OK thanks so much @mzhaase, I had high hopes, but after executing these commands, still no success screen :(  Can I give you any other info that you need to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: If I may recommend, I will remove and re-install if you give me instructions per your precise instructions. Very much appreciate your help @mzhaase. Really not clear on why this is so painful.

Comment: I listed "iptables -L' and I don't see any mention of Port 80. What should I be looking for?

Comment: @mzhasse OK I disabled IPTABLES (/etc/init.d/iptables stop) and http access to server IP address now shows NGINX SUCCESS PAGE! This was a two day aggravating ordeal and excrutiatingly painful, and still not fixed yet (iptables is disabled, not a good solution). Appreciate all your help and you gave some valuable tips but this is still not solved yet. One would think there would be a DIAGNOSTIC TOOL that could find this stuff. If I need a port open, check that it's open. If I need certain folder permissions, check that I have it. If I need something to run, check that I have it.

Comment: The server is no longer accepting puTTY connections. Maybe it was hacked. What an agonizing disaster this has been. Anyway thanks for all help provided. I will update later again when I know more and can fix this.

Comment: @tero-kilkanen & mzhaase Thanks for your debugging help guys. Still not working, but my host reset the server. Then I checked the default IPTABLES rules and there is one rule that denies all traffic. Apparently adding a rule after that rule will not open the port? Please correct me if I am wrong. So then I just added one hash symbol to comment out that one single deny rule. Save the file, and then HTTP access on port 80 starts to work! But two minutes later, with no other changes by me, server goes offline and rejects all connections, and cannot PING. Baffling. Locked out again.

Comment: My host has said the server crashed due to some installation problem and not related to the Port 80 issue. After reboot it seems ok again.

Comment: Consider switching to a better VPS provider. Digital Ocean or AWS both have asian data centers. Latency will still be very low, possibly lower because better routing.

Comment: Thank you @mzhaase yes and I will do some testing. I've got PHP7 installed and making progress step by step. Thank you again.